# Making Dynamically Set Object Values Reactive in VueJS data() & v-bind: sync Forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, vue-reactivity

So, I am building a dynamic form generator that generates forms based on an object created in `data()` as `form: {}`, then set with question key/value pairs in `beforeMount()` that are bound to a form generating child component using `v-bind.sync`.

I want to be able to see changes to the key/value pairs within `form: {}` on the page, but because the key-value pairs are generated on the fly, they are not reactive.

When I log `this.form`, I can see changes to the object values, but I think I am missing a function to get them to refresh on the page itself:

[image: Screenshot of page with console logs]

Parent component, where the empty form object is set:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <DynamicForm
      v-bind.sync="form"
      :questions="questions"
      :onSubmit="onSubmit"
    >
      <template slot="buttons">
        <b-button
          type="submit"
          block
        >
          Submit
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </DynamicForm>

    <div class="form-output">
      {{form}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // ...
  data(){
    return {
      form: {},
// questions normally loaded via http request, set here in data for example's sake
      questions: [
        {
          "type": "TEXT",
          "label": "Name",
          "model": "name"
        },
        {
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "label": "Age",
          "model": "age"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  beforeMount(){
    let questionArray = this.questions

    for(var i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++){
      this.form[questionArray[i].model] = questionArray[i].defaultValue ? questionArray[i].defaultValue : ''
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

The `DynamicForm` component emits like so:

```
<template lang="html">
    <template v-for="question in questions">
        <b-form-input
          :v-model="question.model"
          @input="formInput(question.model, $event)"
        >
        </b-form-input>
    </template>
  </b-form>
<script>
export default {
  // ...
  props: {
    questions: Array,
    onSubmit: Function
  },
  methods: {
    formInput(key, value) {
      console.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`)
      this.$emit(`update:${key}`, value)
    },
  },
  // ...
}
</script>
```

[Click here to view this project on GitHub](https://github.com/njwest/Dynamic-Vue-Forms)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats - use `Vue.set` to add new properties to your `form` object or create completely new object the way you do and then assign it into `form` property....

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, you are my hero @MichalLevý

Answer (score 2):

This answer is courtesy of the [Vue reactivity doc link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) posted heroically by Michael Levy in the comments.

In order to make the dynamically generated form contents reactive, we had to set the form key-value pairs using `Vue.set`, aliased within the component as `this.$set(object, key, value)`

The new `beforeMount()` using `Vue.set` rather than `this.form[questionArray[i].model] = questionArray[i].value`:

```
  beforeMount(){
    let questionArray = this.questions

    for(var i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++){
      var valueToSet = questionArray[i].defaultValue ? questionArray[i].defaultValue : ''

      this.$set(this.form, questionArray[i].model, valueToSet)
    }
  },
```